# React: remove localstorage item on page load

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

this my function to remove item from localstorage

```
const removeItem = () => localStorage.removeItem("key")
```

how to run function when page load, try this but its not working

```js
<div onLoad={removeItem}>
<h1>Successful payment landing page</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Check [react component lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) and [useEffect hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
useEffect(() => { 
    removeItem();
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div onLoad={this.removeItem}>
</div>


//paste this function anywhere above render()
removeItem() {
  localStorage.removeItem("key");
}
```